# Plotting a users route taken on a map using MKPolyline

Tags: objective-c, location, mapkit, core-location, mkpolyline

I'm quite new to Objective-c.

In my app, I'm trying to plot the users taken route onto a map.

Here is what I have so far that just gets the users current location:

```
#import "StartCycleViewController.h"
#import "CrumbPath.h"


@interface StartCycleViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;





@end

@implementation StartCycleViewController

@synthesize cycleLocation = _cycleLocation;
@synthesize currentCycleLocation = _currentCycleLocation;






 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCycleLocation];

    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.containerView];

    [self.containerView addSubview:self.map];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - startCycleLocation

- (void)startCycleLocation{

    if (!_cycleLocation){
        _cycleLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _cycleLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _cycleLocation.distanceFilter = 10;
        _cycleLocation.delegate = self;

    }
    [_cycleLocation startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
    self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",    currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",    currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    }
}



- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if ( [error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown ){
        [self stopLocationManager];
    }
}

- (void) stopLocationManager {
    [self.cycleLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}



@end
```

I've had a look around online and gather that I should use `MKPolyline`and give it coordinates. But I'm just not sure how I would store the locations and then send them use `MKPolyline` to plot the points, continuously while the app is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just create a `NSMutableArray` to hold your locations that you instantiate in `viewDidLoad`. So have `didUpdateToLocation` (or, if supporting iOS 6 and higher, you should use `didUpdateToLocations`) simply add a location to an array, then build a `MKPolyline` from that array, add that `MKPolyline` to the map, and then remove the old `MKPolyline`. Or you could add all of the line segments as individual `MKPolyline` objects, but the idea is the same, create a model to hold you locations (e.g. a `NSMutableArray`) and then add the appropriate `MKPolyline` object(s) to the map view.

For example, you could do something like:

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;

    [self.locations addObject:location];
    NSUInteger count = [self.locations count];

    if (count > 1) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = [(CLLocation *)self.locations[i] coordinate];
        }

        MKPolyline *oldPolyline = self.polyline;
        self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
        if (oldPolyline)
            [self.mapView removeOverlay:oldPolyline];
    }
}
```

And remember to specify how the map is to draw the `MKPolyline`. So set your view controller to be a the `delegate` of your `MKMapView`, and you can then do something like the following:

```
#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}

// for iOS versions prior to 7; see `rendererForOverlay` for iOS7 and later

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        overlayView.strokeColor     = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth       = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) Sorry, I'm still new to all this! I've implemented the code and am getting a few errors, i'm sure its all elementary stuff. I tried to set the view controller a delegate of  MKMapView with [mapView setDelegate:self]; is that right?

Comment: Also I get the following errors @ self.location addObject "no visible @interface for NSArray declares sddObject" and @ self.mapview "not found on object of type". Again i'm sure its something obvious i've done wrong!

Comment: @user3254994 Yes, to specify delegate for the `MKMapView`, you can do it in code like that (or you can do it in IB by going to the "Connections Inspector"). The error regarding `self.locations` is because you defined and/or instantiated it as an `NSArray` rather than as an `NSMutableArray`. Use the latter.

Comment: I've run the app and now get this error - but there don't seem to be any errors in the code *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<StartCycleViewController 0x125650d00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key map.'

Comment: @user3254994 You generally get that error when you have an incorrect outlet defined in Interface Builder (IB). Check your `IBOutlet` definitions in the "Connections Inspector" (that last tab in the right panel in IB) and compare to your `IBOutlet` definitions in your code. Sounds like there's a connection in IB to a non-existent property with the name of `map`

Comment: @Rob I have the same question and have already implemented the first part of your code. Yet, I dont see the polyline being drawn. I want to know if the second part of your code is necessary or should I expect the system to take the default characteristics for the polyline. Kindly help, MapKit confuses me a little.

Comment: @AceN - Yes, you must implement [`mapview:rendererForOverlay:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview?language=objc) (or, [`mapView(_:rendererFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview) in Swift) in your map view delegate (and obviously set the `delegate` of the map view, too). In the absence of that, no (visible) overlay will be rendered.

Comment: @Rob i did what you said and now I can see the ployline. But not the way I expect. I am making an app that tracks user location while he walks/runs, after the user click starts. Initially, the map shows current location, which is appropriate. Then when I click start it updates the locations with markers and draws a polyline from one marker to another. I dont expect to see a polyline until another marker is placed. however, on click start i see a marker from somehwere in africa to my current location, in India! what could be the problem?didupdatelocation doesn't return such a coordinate.

Comment: @Rob i have made a post here regarding my problem, with proper illustration...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471091/tracking-user-location-mkpolyline-getting-drawn-from-utc-coordinates-to-current