# Plotting User route with MKPolyline

Tags: objective-c

The app I am working on I want to track where the user has been and then show the route on a map.

This is the code I have at the moment:

.m :

```
#import "StartCycleViewController.h"



@interface StartCycleViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;


@end

@implementation StartCycleViewController

@synthesize cycleLocation = _cycleLocation;
@synthesize currentCycleLocation = _currentCycleLocation;
@synthesize mapView;






- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startCycleLocation];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;




}


- (void)dealloc
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark - startCycleLocation

- (void)startCycleLocation{

    if (!_cycleLocation){
        _cycleLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _cycleLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        _cycleLocation.distanceFilter = 10;
        _cycleLocation.delegate = self;

    }
    [_cycleLocation startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];



    }
}



- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    if ( [error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown ){
        [self stopLocationManager];
    }
}

- (void) stopLocationManager {
    [self.cycleLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;

    [self.locations addObject:location];
    NSUInteger count = [self.locations count];

    if (count > 1) {
        // only both to add new location if distance has changed by more than 5 meters

        [self.locations addObject:location];
        count = [self.locations count];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = [(CLLocation *)self.locations[i] coordinate];
        }

        MKPolyline *oldPolyline = self.polyline;
        self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:count];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:oldPolyline];
    }
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}





@end
```

.h :

```
@interface StartCycleViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *currentCycleLocation;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *cycleLocation;

@property(nonatomic, strong) MKPolyline *polyline;
@property (nonatomic,strong)    NSMutableArray *locations;




- (void) stopLocationManager;



@end
```

However when the app loads there is no route overlaid on the map. Not sure what I've done wrong here, any Ideas?

Also, I would like the map to zoom in around the route taken, is there a way to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting a users route taken on a map using MKPolyline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498328/plotting-a-users-route-taken-on-a-map-using-mkpolyline)

Comment: I don't see where self.locations is created (alloc+init).  What debugging have you done to try to find where the problem is?  Eg. NSLogs, stepping through the code in the debugger, breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Hi Anna, Sorry I'm still pretty new to this! Haven't done any debugging with breakpoints, NSLogs etc. Will attempt this now!

Comment: @Anna I've initialised the self.locations with self.locations = [NSMutableArray array]; in the viewDidLoad method, but no luck. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple but not exactly sure were to look. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that execution reaches the addOverlay line?  Does rendererForOverlay get called?  Put breakpoints or NSLogs in those places.  Is the mapView IBOutlet connected?

Comment: @Anna, I realised I had some syntax error on this line - `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` as it should have been didUpdateToLocation but still nothing. My mapView is connected to startCycleViewController.m and delegated. I've put NSLogs though out and found that my code never runs the following method: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocations:(NSArray *)locations` and also never calls renderForOverlay.

Comment: Actually, didUpdateLocations is the correct method to use in iOS 6 and up.  The method before iOS 6 was named `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (note singular ToLocation and fromLocation).  The delegate method names must be precise otherwise they'll never get called.  Check location services is turned on and app has permission.  Your posted code looks fine except for the missing array alloc+init which should be done before calling startCycleLocation.  Does startCycleLocation itself get called?  Step through all the code in the debugger and make sure it does what you expect.

Comment: @Anna, it was the didUpdateToLocations that was the problem. All working now many thanks or your help.