# Tracking user location. MKPolyline getting drawn from UTC coordinates (0, 0) to current location

Tags: mapkit, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation, mkpolyline

I am making an app that tracks the route a user takes. I am dropping *MKPointAnnotation* for each location updates with *horizontalAccuracy* >0. Then I'm trying to draw a *MKPolyline* from one point to another. This begins when start button is pressed.
Before pressing the start button the *MKMapView* shows the current location, which is correct. When I press start button I expect to see the point annotation and a polyline drawn from one point to another.

**However, upon pressing start I see a polyline drawn from UTC coordinates (equator and UTC meridian) to my current location, which is undesirable.**

*didUpdateLocation* delegate call of *CLLocationManager* doesn't report any such location when printed using *NSLog*.
Here is the code...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations;
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[locations.count];
    int index=0;
    for (CLLocation *location in locations)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"received co-ordinates:\nlatitude:%f \nlongitude:%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
        #endif
        
        [self centerMapWithCoordinates:location.coordinate];
        
        
        // Add an annotation
        if (location.horizontalAccuracy>0)
        {
            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = location.coordinate;
//            if (location.speed>0)
//            {
                point.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f Kmph",(location.speed*3600/1000)];
//            }
            [self centerMapWithCoordinates:location.coordinate];
            [mapView addAnnotation:point];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            coordinates[index] = coordinate;
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:index+1];
    [mapView addOverlay:polyline];

}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay;
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get rid of this unneeded polyline?

[image: Polyline from UTC coordinates to current location]

If you give code, pleae do so in ObjC. Thanks.

Note:

I noticed after navigating app that all selected coordinates (show by pin annotations) have a polyline with respect to the same above mentioned UTC co-ordinate. See this picture...

[image]

Comment: You want one line that connects the different locations, but you are creating a new line at every location update. Why is that?

Comment: The app is going to track users walk or run workout.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the answer to this even on Apple developer forums. I opened a Technical Support Instance with Apple and turns out I was incrementing the index that would set the size of the C array to by one more than required which resulted into polylines being drawn from co-ordinates (0.0, 0.0).

I changed the code to this...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations;
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"locations array %@",locations);
#endif
    for (int i=0; i<locations.count;i++)
    {
        if (i+1 <locations.count) {
            if (locations[i].horizontalAccuracy>locations[i+1].horizontalAccuracy) {
                currentLocation = locations[i+1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentLocation = locations[i];
        }
        
    }
    
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"current location: %@",currentLocation);
#endif
    [locationArray addObject:currentLocation];
    [self centerMapWithCoordinates:currentLocation.coordinate];
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = currentLocation.coordinate;
    [mapView addAnnotation:point];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[2];
    if (previousLocation!=nil)
    {
        coordinates[0]= previousLocation.coordinate;
        coordinates[1]=currentLocation.coordinate;
        MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:2];
        [mapView addOverlay:polyline];
    }
    else
    {
        previousLocation=[currentLocation copy];
    }
    
    

}
```